# Error in installing Angular

Tags: command-line

I am trying to install angular in Ubuntu, but I am getting this error:

[image: error installing angular]

How can I install angular?

Comment: "permission denied" just means that the user you're logged in as isn't allowed to write to that directory. As Arun answers, you need to elevate your permissions.

Comment: next time please just read through the error message. it says: "please try running this command again as root/administrator". if you google this, you will find a solution yourself :)

Answer (score 2):

You should run

`sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`

Answer (score 1):

as the error message suggests: "please try running this command again as root/administrator".
so log in as a root user, or give yourself root permission in a terminal.

the easiest thing would be to use `sudo`. so `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`.

otherwise you could use `su` to get root and the run your command again

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the sudo to run  all your commands as administrator , then you need to install typescript and angular CLI to setup correctly your [angular environment](https://xpertuto.com/angular-3-steps-to-install-angular-environment/).

sudo npm install -g typescript

sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Comment: Strange: you state to use `sudo` but your examples lack it.  Could you edit your answer to add this?